# How do I slave print to a text file instead of a printer in PuTTY?

Tags: printing, putty

I have a large report that can only be extracted form a legacy system as a print job. 
Printing to screen is impractical as it is 590 pages of text, and printing to screen requests the user to press enter for each new page.

I can print to a specified slave printer in PuTTY, by setting the printer in the terminal settings.

I have created a 'Generic /Text Only' Printer, and selected it in PuTTY.

When I print I get two jobs in the queue;  the first is always 13 bytes - and gives a status of 'Error - Printing', the second is ~2.54 MB, but never prints.

I was expecting a file dialog to open so I could specify a destination file, but I've not had any luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

It's a "feature" of Putty:

> Since PuTTY sends data to the printer raw, it cannot offer options
>   such as portrait versus landscape, print quality, or paper tray
>   selection. All these things would be done by your PC printer driver
>   (which PuTTY bypasses); if you need them done, you will have to find a
>   way to configure your remote server to do them.

PuTTY bypasses the driver that normally puts up the file-name selection dialog box

Update 2:

You could set the server to print to a file and then use PuTTY (it has an SCP client `pscp`) to retrieve that text file.

I have a server that uses zmodem to send files, PuTTY doesn't support zmodem but various forks do, such as Kitty.

(original answer follows)

---

You need to set up a printer that always prints to file

[image: Win 7 dialog]

Then in Putty go to Settings, Terminal, Printer to send ANSI output to. Choose the printer you just added to Windows.

Comment: I did that but it doesn't allow you to specify a file. If you do a test print you can specify a file  - but I get the same behaviour - a 13 byte file and the main file - and they both fail to print (or aske for a destination filename)

Comment: @spdegabrielle: My error - Putty doesn't facilitate what you want to do. See updated answer.

Comment: I'll see about that. leaving the question open in case there is an answer out there.

Answer (score 1):

I ask putty to direct it to a "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" in the default printer insert. Configure ports as "PORTPROMPT". Dumps a .OXPS file to "my documents". Open file with Wordpad and print direct to any printer.